# Laravel Nova, route not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I've installed Laravel Nova (using Laravel 5.6). `App\Providers\NovaServiceProvider::class` is registered in my `config/app.php` file. But when I go to `https://localhost:1234/nova` I get a `404` error.

I have cleared my caches and run a `composer dump-autoload`. How can I get this route working?

EDIT: When I run `php artisan route:list` the `nova-api` routes are there but there is no route for `nova`.

Also, the migrations were not copied across after `nova:install`. I am working with an existing Laravel project.

Comment: Did you run `php artisan nova:install`?

Comment: @ChinLeung Yes - that's how I got `App\Providers\NovaServiceProvider::class` in the `config/app.php` file.

Comment: as you told nova works only for api requests not in browser right?

Comment: this is a test version of this nova dashboard which i would never pay money for it.

Comment: Do you have the file `config/nova.php`?

Comment: @ChinLeung Yes.

Comment: @ChinLeung If it makes a difference, I am using Passport in the app.

Comment: Hmm.. Are you caching your config by any chance? Did you try `php artisan config:clear`?

Comment: @ChinLeung You are right! Please write it as an answer & I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to clear the config cache for the changes to actually apply:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 13):

> Verify App\Providers\NovaServiceProvider is in your provider list.

- Go to `config/app.php`
- Add `App\Providers\NovaServiceProvider::class,` to the `providers`

Note that this answer is relative to [@jszobody's anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52005644/1186123) and a direct answer to a question following up upon that aforementioned tweet.
https://twitter.com/taylorotwell/status/1032300773655408640

Without this, it is possible to see the Nova panel, though it remains empty. A fresh install at this time will show a "Help" Card on the Dashboard.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this problem too. Add `Nova::routes();` to your `routes/web.php` and reload `/nova` in your browser.

Comment: Some progress. Now I get `Trying to get property of non-object (View: /app/resources/views/vendor/nova/partials/user.blade.php)`.

Comment: Are you authenticated ? This partial is trying to get email and name from the authenticated user.

Answer (score 0):

From Taylor (if you are using an earlier version than Nova 1.0.1):

> If you are having issues with Nova not registering a /nova route when using "php artisan serve"... try upgrading Nova and updating your route registration in your NovaServiceProvider to match this image... (add "register" on end of chain).

[image]

https://twitter.com/taylorotwell/status/1032298042773393408

Answer (score 0):

If you have disabled [Package Discovery / Autodiscover](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/packages#package-discovery) by adjusting your composer.json like so:

```
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [
            "*"
        ]
    }
}
```

You need to add the the NovaCoreServiceProvider and Nova alias to your `config/app.php` manually.

```php
'providers' => [
    Laravel\Nova\NovaCoreServiceProvider::class,
],
'aliases' => [
    'Nova' => Laravel\Nova\Nova::class,
]
```

If you look at the composer.json of laravel/nova in your vendor folder you can see this:

```
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "providers": [
            "Laravel\\Nova\\NovaCoreServiceProvider"
        ],
        "aliases": {
            "Nova": "Laravel\\Nova\\Nova"
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Resolved by finally remember to enable HTTP rewrite.

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

then restart apache

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

check if the route does not require an id

for example /student/:id

Comment: More of a comment than an answer

Answer (score 0):

I realize it has been some time since this was posted, and there are other answers, but today I encountered the same problem a fresh install seemingly out of nowhere and resolved it by adding

`\Laravel\Nova\NovaCoreServiceProvider::class` to the `providers` array in `config/app.php`.

After doing so, I ran `artisan route:clear` to clear and rebuild the route cache, and the problem was resolved.

I have no idea what could have caused this issue, as I've bootstrapped multiple new laravel projects with nova the exact same way and never encountered this issue.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to debug to check all Nova routes.
Add the lines above in the NovaServiceProvider class boot() function.

```
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        Nova::serving(function (ServingNova $event) {
            $request = $event->request;
            \Log::debug(Nova::resourceInformation($request));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply if none of solutions works delete **vendor** file and try again